# How do I submit a form using a store under ExtJs?

Tags: forms, extjs, extjs4, store

Is there a way to have a form submit create an object in a store under ExtJs 4?

It seems strange to me that the grid is built completely around the store mechanism and I see no obvious way to plug a form into a store. But I am most likely just missing something.

Comment: Note for those of you stumbling on this question, after becoming more familiar with ExtJS, I have decided that trying to shoe horn stores into forms is a really bad idea. It adds a lot of complexity for very little gain. Consider yourself warned.

Comment: I had the same initial idea, but after a while realized that the form is really for just a single record and didn't need a store.  What I found bizarre however was that I have to call `updateRecord` to apply the form values to the underlying record model.  Thought that would be automatic.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can add a model instance to a store upon form submit using this code:

```
onSaveClick: function()
{
    var iForm         = this.getFormPanel().getForm(),
        iValues       = iForm.getValues(),
        iStore        = this.getTasksStore();

    iStore.add( iValues );
},
```

This is within an MVC controller, so `this` is the controller.

For model editing, you can 'bind' a form to a model instance using `loadRecord`:

```
iFormPanel.loadRecord( this.selection );
```

You can then update the model instance using `updateRecord()`:

```
iFormPanel.getForm().updateRecord();
```

Just for fun (and as it might help some), it is similar to the following code:

```
onSaveClick: function()
{
    var iForm         = this.getFormPanel().getForm(),
        iRecord       = iForm.getRecord(),
        iValues       = iForm.getValues();

    iRecord.set ( iValues );        
},
```

If your store is has `autoSync: true`. An Update (or Create) call will be made via the configured proxy. If there's no autoSync, you'll have to sync your store manually.

Comment: What is `this`, and for `this.getStore()`, how do you associate a store with `this` in the first place?

Comment: Oh sorry, all this code is within an MVC controller, so `this` refer to the controller, the (now edited TasksStore) will be one of its store configs.

Comment: But it matters less - you can use the same concept with `vars`, you simply need an instance of your `form.Panel` and of your `store`. Perhaps provide your code and we'll take it from there.

Comment: OK I follow you. Still not working for me. I'm trying your first method and nothing is happening. Here is what I have so far, http://pastie.org/4402140

Comment: Hmmm... code looks fine, what happens if you do `console.log( store.add(values) );`

Comment: And I take it the model associated with the store has fields matching the `name` configs of your form fields?

Comment: Hmm, looks like it is hitting the store, but I don't see any network traffic to actually create the object based on the proxy.

Comment: Is your store `autoSync` is true? If not just do `store.sync()` right after you add to it.

Comment: `autoSync` is set to true. Not sure what is going wrong here, it should at least be trying to hit the network through the proxy. The store returns an array with the newly added model. So it is going in the store, but not firing the proxy. Even manually calling sync doesn't work.

Comment: What's the proxy definition's like? You have one for `Create`?

Comment: Here is the rest of what I have, http://pastie.org/4402308. I just put the store and model in the same file for pastie, but they are normally separated.

Comment: OK, where exactly PersonStore is created?

Comment: Here is a [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Izhaki/xSAPJ/) with pretty much your code. You should see that the proxy is called there.

Comment: Sorry I omitted the application harness, here is what I have, http://jsfiddle.net/JamesFM/SpK4d/. Notice that I enabled autoLoad and the initial GET load works fine, but the submit sync does not.

Comment: Works for me - I filled the form to satisfy validations, pressed submit, and do get a server request with the right details.

Comment: Ha, that's what it was, that email validation was screwing me up. Thanks for going above and beyond.

Comment: Consider using [formBind](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.Component-cfg-formBind) to prevent such issues. As the docs say, have a look at Ext.form.Panel for an example.

Comment: That's a good point, but if you are just using model validators then formbind won't work. Model validators seem pretty half baked though, so I think I just use form validators from now on.

Answer (score 3):

You can subclass Ext.form.action.Action to provide load/save actions for a Form to be performed on a Store. The only gotcha is that somehow there's no "official" way to select any non-standard Action in Ext.form.Basic, so I'd suggest an unofficial override:

```
Ext.define('Ext.form.Advanced', {
    override: 'Ext.form.Basic',

    submit: function(options) {
        var me = this,
            action;

        options = options              || {};
        action  = options.submitAction || me.submitAction;

        if ( action ) {
            return me.doAction(action, options);
        }
        else {
            return me.callParent(arguments);
        }
    },

    load: function(options) {
        var me = this,
            action;

        options = options            || {};
        action  = options.loadAction || me.loadAction;

        if ( action ) {
            return me.doAction(action, options);
        }
        else {
            return me.callParent(arguments);
        }
    }
});
```

And, having created the Actions you need, you could then use them in a Form Panel:

```
Ext.define('My.form.Panel', {
    extend: 'Ext.form.Panel',

    requires: [ 'Ext.form.Advanced' ],

    loadAction: 'My.load.Action',
    submitAction: 'My.submit.Action',

    ...
});
```

There are other ways and shortcuts though.

Comment: I am most likely just being dense, but how does this override help you connect the form to the store? What does this buy you over just assigning a function to the onButtonClick event?

Comment: A form uses Actions to load and submit data. By using Action other than standard Submit you can change the data handling logic without coupling it tightly with your Form. What happens when your Store changes? Where would you prefer to handle *action* specifics? There's an Action already, it just doesn't do what you need in that particular case. To me it makes every sense to replace that Action with the one that would load data from Store and save it into Store.

Comment: I gave this method a try and having loadAction and submitAction defined as properties on the panel doesn't seem to pass them to the action panel. I can put it as an option on the submit invocation, but no on the panel itself.