# In ExtJS how do I load an object into a form field?

Tags: forms, extjs, extjs4

If I have a JSON response like,

```
{
    "something": "foo",
    "subobject": {
        "id": "bar",
        "name": "baz"
    }
}
```

I am loading the response into a form using `form.setValues(responseObject)`.

If I have `displayfield` in the form that is subobject, how do I put that name from the subobject into that field? Or better yet, how do I put the name and the id into that field?

I tried a custom renderer, but the value parameter passed into the renderer is a string containing `"[object Object]"`.

I am using ExtJS 4.1.3. Anyone have any advice?

Comment: you will probably be better served in a long run by using Models and Stores and setting your form fields with form.loadRecord(record)

Comment: @dbrin, it's funny you should say that. I just added a comment to my question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11835729/ to the effect that using stores and forms together is a giant pain.

Comment: @dbrin, Btw, that previous comment wasn't intended as a put down.From my experience stores and forms don't seemed designed for interoperability. But I am still very much an ExtJS novice.

Comment: depending on what you are aming to do with forms and how complex your data model is it can get difficult. however for most cases this relationship works just fine: take a look at this example from Sencha http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/example/writer/writer.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Got it to work by adding the following to my displayfield config

```
valueToRaw: function(value) {
    return value;
}
```

The standard valueToRaw converts the object to a string, which is of no use to anyone.

I then added this custom renderer to display my field as a link,

```
renderer: function(value, field) {
    if (!value) { 
        return; 
    }
    return "<a href='" + value.id + "'> " + value.name + "</a>";
}
```

I feel like I should be able to use a template instead of a custom renderer, but I had no luck getting that working.